# Making a script in debian which would create a new file from names file with different order of the names

Tags: shell, debian

Existing names in the "names" file is in form of lastname1,firstname1 ; lastname2,firstname2.

In the new file it should be like down below.

Create a script that outputs a list of existing users (from the "names" file) in the form:

```
firstname1.lastname1
firstname2.lastname2
etc.
```

And saves a file called "cat list"

Comment: Shouldn't you be good to go with a stream editor like `sed`? You should be able to use regular expression captures to reverse the last/first name order and apply further filters such as replacing ';' with newline.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of command line should be a solution for you :

```
 awk -F '\.' '{print $2","$1}' source_file >> "cat list"
```

- First *awk* revers the order of the field and put the char ',' under
- ">>" Second step redirect full output to a file called "cat list" as requested

Comment: I'd thought about using `awk` as well. It might be better than using `tr` and `sed`. The example you've posted will effectively replace periods with commas and reverse the name fields. However, it does not remove semi-colons and the question author actually wanted the periods!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I have the most efficient solution here but it works and outputs the different stages of translation to help illustrate the process:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "lastname1,firstname1 ; lastname2,firstname2" >testfile
echo "original file:"
cat testfile
echo "\n"

# first replace semi-colon with newline
tr ';' '\n' <testfile >testfile_n
echo "after first translation:"
cat testfile_n
echo "\n"

# also remove extra spaces
tr -d '[:blank:]' <testfile_n >testfile_n_s
echo "after second translation:"
cat testfile_n_s
echo "\n"

# now swap name order using sed and use periods instead of commas
sed -E 's/([a-zA-Z0-9]*),([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/\2\.\1/g' testfile_n_s >"cat list"
echo "after third iteration:"
cat "cat list"
echo "\n"
```

The script above will save a file called 'cat list' and output something similar to:

```
original file:
lastname1,firstname1 ; lastname2,firstname2


after first translation:
lastname1,firstname1
 lastname2,firstname2


after second translation:
lastname1,firstname1
lastname2,firstname2


after third iteration:
firstname1.lastname1
firstname2.lastname2
```